# Visual Studio Mac does not set Android SDK path correctly

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

When I try to build my Xamarin.Forms Project for Android I get this error:

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(5,5): Error XARSD7023: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/ninopadrutt/Library/Android/sdk'.
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1[TResult].CreateDirectoryHandle (System.String path, System.Boolean ignoreNotFound) [0x00032] in <36514b14425c4337b446653c547aa9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1[TResult]..ctor (System.String directory, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00048] in <36514b14425c4337b446653c547aa9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1+DelegateEnumerator[TResult]..ctor (System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[TResult] enumerable) [0x00000] in <36514b14425c4337b446653c547aa9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1[TResult]..ctor (System.String directory, System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1+FindTransform[TResult] transform, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00042] in <36514b14425c4337b446653c547aa9c3>:0 
  at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserDirectories (System.String directory, System.String expression, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Enumeration/FileSystemEnumerableFactory.cs:104 
  at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchTarget searchTarget, System.IO.EnumerationOptions options) [0x00045] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs:180 
  at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.EnumerationOptions enumerationOptions) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs:196 
  at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs:193 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.FindBestNDK (System.String androidSdkPath) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase+<GetAllAvailableAndroidNdks>d__73.MoveNext () [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:164 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.GetValidNdkPath (System.String ctorParam) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:128 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkBase.Initialize (System.String androidSdkPath, System.String androidNdkPath, System.String javaSdkPath) [0x00061] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/Sdks/AndroidSdkBase.cs:71 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdkInfo..ctor (System.Action`2[T1,T2] logger, System.String androidSdkPath, System.String androidNdkPath, System.String javaSdkPath) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/AndroidSdkInfo.cs:18 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.RefreshAndroidSdk (System.String sdkPath, System.String ndkPath, System.String javaPath, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper logHelper) [0x00005] in <e0b267300cf54583bbaa8d3ab5dc4081>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveSdks.RunTask () [0x000ac] in <e0b267300cf54583bbaa8d3ab5dc4081>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <e0b267300cf54583bbaa8d3ab5dc4081>:0  (XARSD7023) (MoneyFox.Android)
```

So it seems it looks for the SDK in this path: /Users/ninopadrutt/Library/Android/sdk. And in here it actually isn't available.
But in the Visual Studio Preferences is this path defined and under this path it is acutally available: /Users/ninopadrutt/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

So it seems that the path is not correctly applied. I tried reinstalling everything without success. Is there another way how I can enforce that?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed on your computer?

Comment: no, I had JetBrains Rider installed with their Version of Xamarin Android. So I can think of that this overwrote something. I did uninstall that as well. But so far I just have not found any way to reset the path.

Comment: You could reset the path in the vs mac `Preferences  -> Android `

Comment: That is what I tried. But as written in my original post, in that view there is a different path than what the build seems to refer to. I also tried to change that to a different path and reset to default with no success.

Comment: Same issue here. Preferences -> Android says "/Users/adams-family/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx" but I get an error "Could not find a part of the path '/Users/adams-family/Library/Android/sdk'". Brand new macbook, clean install :(

Comment: I found a workaround: 1) Close VS, 2) Run in terminal: mkdir /Users/<username>/Library/Android; ln -s /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk; 3) Start VS - still, MS should fix this problem.